# ! Package fontspec Error: The font "標楷體" cannot be found

Tags: fonts

when I compile the latex project, shows error:

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "標楷體" cannot be found.
```

I have already put the font 標楷體.ttf to system folder `/usr/share/fonts/` in linux, why still could not found the font? This is how I set the font:

```
\setCJKmainfont[AutoFakeBold=true,AutoFakeSlant=true]{標楷體}
```

this is the font path:

```
/usr/share/fonts/zh/tw # ls -alh
total 10M
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Oct 10 10:32 .
drwxr-xr-x    9 root     root        4.0K Oct 10 10:31 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        9.9M Oct 10 10:32 標楷體.ttf
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? I can see the font like this:

```
/usr/share/fonts/zh/tw # fc-list|grep "標楷體"
/usr/share/fonts/zh/tw/標楷體.ttf: AR PL KaitiM Big5,文鼎ＰＬ中楷:style=Regular
```

I have tried to copy the fonts to these folder:

```
~/.fonts/
working folder
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/
```

still could not found. I can found the fonts:

```
/usr/share/fonts/zh/tw # fc-list|grep "標楷體"
/root/.fonts/標楷體.ttf: AR PL KaitiM Big5,文鼎ＰＬ中楷:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/zh/tw/標楷體.ttf: AR PL KaitiM Big5,文鼎ＰＬ中楷:style=Regular
/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/標楷體.ttf: AR PL KaitiM Big5,文鼎ＰＬ中楷:style=Regular
```

Comment: Are you sure that `/usr/share/fonts/zh/tw` is one of the folders searched by `fontspec`? Have you tried specifying an explicit path option?

Comment: yes, I am sure the path is the search path because I put all the misssing fonts in the folder /usr/share/fonts , all works fine except the 標楷體.ttf.

Comment: have you re-run fc-cache since adding the font?

Comment: yes, I have already run  fc-cache .

Comment: the filename is different, but is this a different font to this font in texlive (AR PL KaitiM Big5)  `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/arphic-ttf/bkai00mp.ttf: AR PL KaitiM Big5,文鼎ＰＬ中楷:style=Regular`

Comment: `\setCJKmainfont[AutoFakeBold=true,AutoFakeSlant=true]{bkai00mp.ttf}` would give the texlive copy

Comment: Not only TeX, but also I would have a problem finding a font with such a name.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the font name is not `標楷體`, using this command to check the font name:

```
/app # fc-list :lang=zh-tw|grep "標楷體"
/usr/share/fonts/zh/tw/標楷體.ttf: AR PL KaitiM Big5,文鼎ＰＬ中楷:style=Regular
```

the font name is `AR PL KaitiM Big5`.

Comment: Problem solved. But: I wonder why the system identified the font by its CJK characters, rather than by its Latin character name? This suggests that different encodings are used. A mystery.

Comment: the font full name should be `R PL KaitiM Big5,文鼎ＰＬ中楷`, but I could not use the `R PL KaitiM Big5,文鼎ＰＬ中楷`. it also told could not be found. the name make me confusing. The latin name works.